# How do I change link style in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know this sounds like an obvious question and answer, but I have spent a long time trying to figure this out, and for some reason, none of the answers are not working for me. Honestly, this is probably going to be a simple obvious answer I just can't catch. But here's the problem: I am making a website out of HTML5, CSS, and some PHP.

The issue is, that my links appear blue and purple with an underline. I know this is how they are supposed to look, but I have tried many different ways to re-style the links with `text-decoration: none`, and different colors and so on.

Here is my CSS and the HTML part with a link:

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: brown;
}

.sidebar {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #BC986A;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.side-option {
 width: 100%;
 height: 155px;
 background-color: #BC986A;
}

.side-option:hover, .side-option:focus {
 background-color: #DAAD86;
}

.side-name {
 font-family: "Indie Flower", cursive;
 font-size: 1.8em;
 margin: 2px 2px 0px 7px;
 padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.side-image {
 width: 150px;
 height: 97px;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
 border: 0.3em solid #FBEEC1;
}

.info {
 background-color: #659DBD;
 width: 75%;
 height: 100%;
 float: right;
}

#name {
 font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive;
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FBEEC1;
}

#s-name {
 font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FBEEC1;
}

#image {
 display: block;
 width: 384px;
 height: 256px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: 0.5em solid #BC986A;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#desc {
 font-family: "Rock Salt", cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #DAAD86;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <a href="index.php?page=0"><div class="side-option">
  <h2 class="side-name">Brown Bear</h2>
  <img src="http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Animal-Brown-Bear-Beast-Bear-Teddy-Bear-Mammal-422682.jpg" class="side-image" alt="Brown bear standing in tall plants.">
 </div></a>
```

I'm not sure if you needed all that, but there it is anyway.

Comment: `</div></a>` ==> `</a></div>` for start

Comment: He has a div inside the a, so I think he needs an extra `</div>` on the end. He could probably move the `side_option` class onto the `a` and lose the inner div, but obviously can't be certain.

Comment: At first do it in the .css file  --> a {
 text-decoration: none;
} and then apply the other styles

Comment: @mumu `text-decoration: none` would probably only be used to discard the default underline from the links.

Comment: It will discard all default style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  hover  color change  you can  use  this  css

```
   .sidebar a:hover{color:red; }
```

For  keep the  color  focus  after  click

```
  .sidebar a:focus{color:blue; }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to change your code from `</div></a>` at the end to this: `</div></a></div>`

2)Links can be styled differently depending on what state they are in.:

```
    a:link - a normal, unvisited link
    a:visited - a link the user has visited
    a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
    a:active - a link the moment it is clicked
```

You can read more about this in: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

a, a:link, a:visited{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: brown;
}

a:hover, a:active{
  color: green;
}

.sidebar {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #BC986A;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.side-option {
 width: 100%;
 height: 155px;
 background-color: #BC986A;
}

.side-option:hover, .side-option:focus {
 background-color: #DAAD86;
}

.side-name {
 font-family: "Indie Flower", cursive;
 font-size: 1.8em;
 margin: 2px 2px 0px 7px;
 padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.side-image {
 width: 150px;
 height: 97px;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
 border: 0.3em solid #FBEEC1;
}

.info {
 background-color: #659DBD;
 width: 75%;
 height: 100%;
 float: right;
}

#name {
 font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive;
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FBEEC1;
}

#s-name {
 font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FBEEC1;
}

#image {
 display: block;
 width: 384px;
 height: 256px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: 0.5em solid #BC986A;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#desc {
 font-family: "Rock Salt", cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #DAAD86;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <a href="index.php?page=0"><div class="side-option">
  <h2 class="side-name">Brown Bear</h2>
  <img src="http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Animal-Brown-Bear-Beast-Bear-Teddy-Bear-Mammal-422682.jpg" class="side-image" alt="Brown bear standing in tall plants."/>
    </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: brown;
}
```

is where you need to make changes to edit `<a href=""></a>` links

to change hover options:

```
a:hover {
    style it here
}
```

and for already visited links on your site:

```
a:visited {
    style it here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to *style* links.

```css
a{
    color: red;
    cursor: wait;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: color 0.3s, text-shadow 0.3s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    color: green;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #000;
    text-decoration: overline;
}
a:active{
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com" title="Does this annoy you?">Working link.</a>
```